# PropertyChanged sets the old value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have a tree view and when some item label changed it should be applied to all children. 
I use the following method for applying a label to children:

```
    public void SetCLassificationForChildren(TreeItemViewModel item, Labels label)
    {
        if (item == null) return;

        item.Label = label;

        item.Children?.ForEach(c => SetCLassificationForChildren(c, label));
    }
```

Here is a Label-property and INotifyPropertyChanged implementation:

```
...
    public Labels Label
    {
        get => _label;
        set
        {
            _label = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Label);
        }
    }

...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var body = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(body.Member.Name));
    }
```

So, when the property got the label value the following is performed:

_label = value - works fine

but, after that the following row:

OnPropertyChanged(() => Label) raises the set-code again and sets the old value.

I have no idea why it is so.

**UPD** "Labels" is my enumeration type:

```
public enum Labels
{
    NotClassified = 0,
    Internal,
    Confidential,
    StrictlyConf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to converter:

```
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || !(bool)value) return null;

        string btnLabelString = parameter as string;

        Labels btnLabel;

        switch (btnLabelString)
        {
            case "internal":
                btnLabel = Labels.Internal;
                break;
            case "confidential":
                btnLabel = Labels.Confidential;
                break;
            case "strictlyConf":
                btnLabel = Labels.StrictlyConf;
                break;
            default:
                btnLabel = Labels.NotClassified;
                break;
        }

        return btnLabel;
    }
```

It returned the old value, but I added

if (value == null || !(bool)value) return null;

and handled the case in the setter:

```
    public Labels Label
    {
        get => _label;
        set
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                _label = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Label);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Label-property and INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

```
private Labels _label;
public Labels Label
{
   get { return _label; }
   set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _label = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Label");
            }
        }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
{
    var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
    if (propertyChanged != null)
    {
        string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```